# How to make a generic method that calls different services

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm working with Angular and have this method:

```js
  loadPagedRecords() {
    this.loadingSpinner = true;
    this.subPage = this.administratorService.getPage(AppSettings.RECORDS_PER_PAGE)
      .subscribe(resp => {
        this.page.recordsList = resp.content;
        this.page.totalElements = resp.totalElements;

        this.pager = this.pagerService.getPager(this.page.totalElements, 1, AppSettings.RECORDS_PER_PAGE);
        this.pagedItems = this.page.recordsList.slice(this.pager.startIndex, this.pager.endIndex + 1);

        this.loadingSpinner = false;
      }, (error) => {
        this.loadingSpinner = false;
      });
  }
```

This method is responsible for loading all records of Administrators in it Listing Component. The problem is I have others Listing Components (Clients, Services, Payments) and I repeat the same method (the difference is the service that will be called) in all of those Components.

What I want to do is to create a Abstract Class with this method but the variable it subscribes needs to be generic. In the example above it makes a subscribe to the `administratorService` .

How can I make it generic to works with all my listing components?

**EDIT:**

I made some changes and now the method is working the way I wanted... But not sure if this is a good solution:

```js
export abstract class BaseList {

       constructor(protected service: any, protected pagerService: any) {}

  loadPagedRecords() {
    this.loadingSpinner = true;
    this.subPage = this.service.getPage(AppSettings.RECORDS_PER_PAGE)
      .subscribe(resp => {
        this.page.recordsList = resp.content;
        this.page.totalElements = resp.totalElements;

        this.pager = this.pagerService.getPager(this.page.totalElements, 1, AppSettings.RECORDS_PER_PAGE);
        this.pagedItems = this.page.recordsList.slice(this.pager.startIndex, this.pager.endIndex + 1);

        this.loadingSpinner = false;
      }, (error) => {
        this.loadingSpinner = false;
      });
  }


}
```

```js
export class ListAdministratorsComponent extends BaseList implements OnInit {

  constructor(private titleService: Title, private router: Router,
    protected administratorsService: AdministratorsService,
    protected pagerService: PagerService,
    private toastrService: ToastrService
  ) { 
       super(administradoresService, pagerService); 
    }

  ngOnInit() {
       this.loadPagedRecords();
  }

}
```

What do you think?

Comment: you mean to say that the data model will change for each functionality

Comment: @Aravind It's just this line that changes: this.administratorService.getPage() . I need to set the service var that I injected in the constructor according to the Component. For example, if user is visiting ListAdministrator it needs to use administratorService, but if he is visiting ListClients it needs to use clientsService to get the right data.

Comment: Please see my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jovqvm). Here is an example how to create abstract service and override it from different places. Also I highly recommend you to read about [services](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services) and their [scopes](https://angular.io/guide/providers#providing-a-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing the exact structure of your application, so I cannot say if there is a better way, but you could think about using an abstract class:

```
export abstract class RecordViewer<T> {
  abstract readonly serviceGetter = (...args?: any[]) => Observable<T>;

  loadPagedRecords() {
    this.loadingSpinner = true;
    this.subPage = this.serviceGetter(AppSettings.RECORDS_PER_PAGE).pipe(
      finalize(() => this.loadingSpinner = false)
    ).subscribe(resp => {
      this.page.recordsList = resp.content;
      this.page.totalElements = resp.totalElements;
      this.pager = this.pagerService.getPager(
        this.page.totalElements, 1, AppSettings.RECORDS_PER_PAGE
      );
      this.pagedItems = this.page.recordsList.slice(
        this.pager.startIndex, this.pager.endIndex + 1
      );
    });
  }
}
```

which you can then extend from your component:

```
export class AdministratorComponent extends RecordViewer<Administrator> {
  readonly serviceGetter = this.administratorService.getPage;

  constructor(private administratorService: AdministratorService) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I'm gonna try it...I made an edit in the post could you please check if it's acceptable?

Comment: @Andre doesn't your edit still make the same service being called? Perhaps I didn't understand the question

Comment: Ooops, I edited it again, sorry. As you can see now the constructor of the Abstract Class has the variable service with type any. So now I can use it with every listing component. For example, in ListClientsComponents I'm gonna use super(clientsService, pagerService); and the method will subscribe for getPage() from ClientsService.... What do you think?

Comment: @Andre looks goodish, but you should also make your services extend some sort of class or interface to host the getPage method. This way you don't use `any` in your base class